# Swift "retry" logic on request

Tags: swift, alamofire

So i'm a bit lost on how to implement a retry logic when my upload request fail.

Here is my code i would like some guidance on how to do it

```
func startUploading(failure failure: (NSError) -> Void, success: () -> Void, progress: (Double) -> Void) {
        DDLogDebug("JogUploader: Creating jog: \(self.jog)")

        API.sharedInstance.createJog(self.jog,
            failure: { error in
                failure(error)
            }, success: {_ in
                success()
        })
    }
```

Comment: Check out my answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38720898/319805

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's a general solution that can be applied to any async function that has no parameters, excepting the callbacks. I simplified the logic by having only `success` and `failure` callbacks, a `progress` should not be that hard to add.

So, assuming that your function is like this:

```
func startUploading(success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
    DDLogDebug("JogUploader: Creating jog: \(self.jog)")

    API.sharedInstance.createJog(self.jog,
        failure: { error in
            failure(error)
        }, success: {_ in
            success()
    })
}
```

A matching `retry` function might look like this:

```
func retry(times: Int, task: @escaping(@escaping () -> Void, @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Void, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
    task(success, 
        { error in
            // do we have retries left? if yes, call retry again
            // if not, report error
            if times > 0 {
                retry(times - 1, task: task, success: success, failure: failure)
            } else {
                failure(error)
            }
        })
}
```

and can be called like this:

```
retry(times: 3, task: startUploading,
    success: {
        print("Succeeded")
    },
    failure: { err in
        print("Failed: \(err)")
})
```

The above will retry the `startUploading` call three times if it keeps failing, otherwise will stop at the first success.

**Edit**. Functions that do have other params can be simply embedded in a closure:

```
func updateUsername(username: String, success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
    ...
}

retry(times: 3, { success, failure in updateUsername(newUsername, success, failure) },
    success: {
        print("Updated username")
    },
    failure: {
        print("Failed with error: \($0)")
    }
)
```

---

**Update** So many `@escaping` clauses in the `retry` function declaration might decrease its readability, and increase the cognitive load when it comes to consuming the function. To improve this, we can write a simple generic struct that has the same functionality:

```swift
struct Retrier<T> {
    let times: UInt
    let task: (@escaping (T) -> Void, @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Void
    
    func callAsFunction(success: @escaping (T) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
        let failureWrapper: (Error) -> Void = { error in
            // do we have retries left? if yes, call retry again
            // if not, report error
            if times > 0 {
                Retrier(times: times - 1, task: task)(success: success, failure: failure)
            } else {
                failure(error)
            }
        }
        task(success, failureWrapper)
    }
    
    func callAsFunction(success: @escaping () -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) where T == Void {
        callAsFunction(success: { _ in }, failure: failure)
    }
}
```

Being callable, the struct can be called like a regular function:

```swift
Retrier(times: 3, task: startUploading)(success: { print("success: \($0)") },
                                        failure: { print("failure: \($0)") })
```

, or can be circulated through the app:

```swift
let retrier = Retrier(times: 3, task: startUploading)
// ...
// sometime later
retrier(success: { print("success: \($0)") },
        failure: { print("failure: \($0)") })
```

Comment: Can I ask what does the "in" mean here in "retry(3, { success, failure in updateUsername(newUsername, success, failure) }"?
Thanks.

Comment: @allenlinli `in` here represents `Swift`'s separator between a closure arguments and it's body

Answer (score 9):

Here is an updated answer for swift 3. I also added a generic object in the success block so if you make an object after your network call is complete you can pass it along to the final closure. Here is the retry function:

```
func retry<T>(_ attempts: Int, task: @escaping (_ success: @escaping (T) -> Void, _ failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) -> Void, success: @escaping (T) -> Void, failure: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {
task({ (obj) in
  success(obj)
}) { (error) in
  print("Error retry left \(attempts)")
  if attempts > 1 {
    self.retry(attempts - 1, task: task, success: success, failure: failure)
  } else {
      failure(error)
    }
  }
}
```

And here is how you would use it if you updated a user and wanted to get back a new user object with the updated info:

```
NetworkManager.shared.retry(3, task: { updatedUser, failure in
NetworkManager.shared.updateUser(user, success: updatedUser, error: failure) }
, success: { (updatedUser) in
  print(updatedUser.debugDescription)
}) { (err) in
  print(err)
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin, 
is possible used it with this function: func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask

Thank

Answer (score 1):

Updated to swift 5, with **Result** type instead of success and failure blocks.

```
func retry<T>(_ attempts: Int, task: @escaping (_ completion:@escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) -> Void,  completion:@escaping (Result<T, Error>) -> Void) {

    task({ result in
        switch result {
        case .success(_):
            completion(result)
        case .failure(let error):
            print("retries left \(attempts) and error = \(error)")
            if attempts > 1 {
                self.retry(attempts - 1, task: task, completion: completion)
            } else {
                completion(result)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This is how we can use the retry function:

```
func updateUser(userName: String) {
retry(3, task: { (result) in
    startUploadingWithResult(userName: userName, completion: result)
}) { (newResult) in
    switch newResult {
    case .success(let str):
        print("Success : \(str)")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
  }
}

 updateUser(userName: "USER_NAME")
```