# Swift Async Request Retry for AWS S3 Upload

Tags: swift, asynchronous, amazon-s3

I've been trying to figure out how to upload multiple files (images) to AWS S3 from Swift. I asked a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48603506/handle-multiple-file-image-uploads-to-aws-s3-swift) but did not receive any responses. Rather than try & ask the same question again, I'm hoping to find guidance on creating a retry function/wrapper for a function that fires a network request w/ a completion handler. I found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905900/swift-retry-logic-on-request) & have tried to model it similarly. The answers by Cristik & JustinM are written in Swift 3, so when trying to write them in Swift 4, I had to make some changes. Sadly, I'm worried I lost some logic in the conversion (I don't fully understand everything that they suggested, so some of my changes were just suggestions by Xcode). Here is what I have refactored from their question & implementing the AWS S3 Transfer Utility:

```
static func retryFunction(numberOfTimes: Int, task: @escaping (_ success: @ escaping (String) -> (), _ failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) -> (), success: @escaping (String) -> (), failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    task({ (result) in
        success(result)
    }) { (error) in
        if numberOfTimes > 1 {
            print("retrying with \(numberOfTimes - 1)")
            self.retryFunction(numberOfTimes: numberOfTimes - 1, task: task, success: success, failure: failure)
        } else {
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}

static func singleImageUploadAttempt(_ dataToUpload: Data, _ imageKey: String,
                                     _ success: @escaping (String) -> (), _ failure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {

    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()
    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

    completionHandler = { (task, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("failure to upload the image: \(imageKey)")
            failure(error)
        } else{
            print("\(imageKey) uploaded successfully")
            success(imageKey)
        }
    }

    transferUtility.uploadData(dataToUpload, bucket: s3BucketName, key: imageKey, contentType: "image/png",
                               expression: expression, completionHandler: completionHandler).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject! in

                                if let error = task.error {
                                    print("An error occurred generating the task")
                                    failure(error)
                                }

                                return nil;
    }

}

static func uploadImages(imagesToUpload: [UIImage], complete: @escaping (String?) -> ()) {
    let folderKey = UUID().uuidString
    var retryArray = [String: Data]()
    let imageGroup = DispatchGroup()

    for i in 0..<imagesToUpload.count {
        let resizedImage = compressImage(imageToReduce: imagesToUpload[i], expectedSizeInMb: 2)
        let imageKey = "public/\(folderKey)/image\(i).png"
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(resizedImage!)
        retryArray[imageKey] = imageData!

        imageGroup.enter()
        retryFunction(numberOfTimes: 3, task: { success, failure in singleImageUploadAttempt(imageData!, imageKey,
                                                                                             success, failure) },
            success: { (keyToRemove) in
                retryArray.removeValue(forKey: keyToRemove)
                print("updated")
                print("successfully uploaded \(imageKey)")
                imageGroup.leave()
            },
            failure: { (err) in
                print("failed to upload \(imageKey)")
                imageGroup.leave()
            }
        )
    }
    imageGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        if(retryArray.keys.count > 0) {
            print("the images could not be uploaded")
            complete(nil)
        } else {
            print("all images uploaded successfully")
            complete(folderKey)
        }
    }

}
```

Right now, the image upload works fine when I have a connection. When I try without a connection, however, the function just waits infinitely. It calls the singleImageUploadAttempt for each image but doesn't hit the completion handler or task.error. None of my print statements are fired, and rather than hitting the function 3 times for each image (3 retries), it hits the imageGroup.notify() and then just does nothing. I apologize if I misspoke on any of this - I'm still trying to understand all of this Swift logic/syntax. I appreciate any help/suggestions, thank you!

Comment: Define "infinitely".  When are you expecting it to stop trying?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-transfer-files-with-transfer-utility.html#limitations

Comment: My b - "infinitely" as in it just seems to never execute the next step, as if it's waiting for something that will never finish. It's only 5 images at most, so I'm expecting it to only take a few seconds or so. I was expecting every image upload task to fail in the uploadData method of singleImageUploadAttempt right away because of no internet connection, but it doesn't

Comment: So I don't think that the AWS S3 SDK makes any promise about timing out in "a few seconds".  And it seems redundant to build your own retry logic -- I believe the SDK is handling that to some extent. The SDK does give you a mechanism for tracking progress.  You could use that and some GCD stuff to fail after a few seconds if no progress is reported. Sorry, I don't have a working example to show you.

Comment: Thanks! That may work - I just built a retry wrapper as I was going to be doing multiple requests & wasn't sure how to track them. I was just assuming it would instantly fail as it didn't have internet - it seemed to do it when I had it outside of the retry logic & just calling the function by itself.

Comment: See this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html

Comment: Default timeout for _transferUtility.uploadData_ is 50 minutes.
Try [this code](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/773#issuecomment-394452497) for setting custom timeout.